# pandas:add a column based on another one

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add a column based on column 'mths_since_recent_revol_delinq',if mths_since_recent_revol_delinq is null then get the new column equals 1,and get new dataframe like:

```
+----+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|    | mths_since_recent_revol_delinq | mths_since_recent_revol_delinq_add |
+----+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|  0 | NaN                            |                                  1 |
|  1 | 33                             |                                  0 |
|  2 | NaN                            |                                  1 |
|  3 | NaN                            |                                  1 |
|  4 | 57                             |                                  0 |
|  5 | 21                             |                                  0 |
|  6 | 60                             |                                  0 |
|  7 | NaN                            |                                  1 |
|  8 | 2                              |                                  0 |
|  9 | 24                             |                                  0 |
| 10 | NaN                            |                                  1 |
+----+--------------------------------+------------------------------------+

def label_race (df):
   if df['mths_since_recent_revol_delinq'].isnull():
      return 1
   else:
      return 0

Loan_a1['mths_since_recent_revol_delinq_add'] = Loan_a1.apply (lambda df: label_race(df),axis=1)
```

and Traceback :

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 Loan_a1['mths_since_recent_revol_delinq_add'] = Loan_a1.apply (lambda df: label_race(df),axis=1)
>
> D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self,
>   func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)    4150
>   if reduce is None:    4151                         reduce = True
>   -> 4152                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)    4153             else:    4154
>   return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)
>
> D:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in
>   _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)    4246             try:    4247                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
>   -> 4248                     results[i] = func(v)    4249                     keys.append(v.name)    4250             except Exception as e:
>
> in (df)
>   ----> 1 Loan_a1['mths_since_recent_revol_delinq_add'] = Loan_a1.apply (lambda df: label_race(df),axis=1)
>
> in label_race(df)
>         1 def label_race (df):
>   ----> 2    if df['mths_since_recent_revol_delinq'].isnull():
>         3       return 1
>         4    else:
>         5       return 0
>
> AttributeError: ("'float' object has no attribute 'isnull'", 'occurred
>   at index 0')

any ideas on how to fix it?thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) and then cast the result to int with [astype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
Loan_a1 = pd.DataFrame({'mths_since_recent_revol_delinq': [np.nan, 33.0, np.nan, np.nan, 57.0, 21.0, 60.0, np.nan, 2.0, 24.0, np.nan]})
```

---

```
results_key = "mths_since_recent_revol_delinq_add"
input_key = "mths_since_recent_revol_delinq"
Loan_a1[results_key] = Loan_a1[input_key].isnull().astype(int)
print (Loan_a1)
    mths_since_recent_revol_delinq  mths_since_recent_revol_delinq_add
0                              NaN                                   1
1                             33.0                                   0
2                              NaN                                   1
3                              NaN                                   1
4                             57.0                                   0
5                             21.0                                   0
6                             60.0                                   0
7                              NaN                                   1
8                              2.0                                   0
9                             24.0                                   0
10                             NaN                                   1
```

Comment: @Luca Cappelletti - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves your issue with minimal changes:

```
def label_race (df):
   if pd.isna(df['mths_since_recent_revol_delinq']):
      return 1
   else:
      return 0

Loan_a1['mths_since_recent_revol_delinq_add'] = Loan_a1.apply (lambda df: 
label_race(df),axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Following @Jezrael's construction and definitions and the neat trick that `True * 1 = 1` and `False * 1 = 0` you can obtain the same result using (also assign):

```
Loan_a1.assign(results_key = lambda x:x[input_key].isnull() * 1)
```

Note that this approach directly returns a new data frame. No further assignment is necessary

Comment: could you please explain the downvote? The solution shows, uses assign, which makes it easier to be used in a pipeline and does not require the cast to int. Otherwise it returns the same output